# Recall and Precision ML models

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I use decision trees for a binary classification. To evaluate the model, I use K-fold cross-validation, where k = 10.
When I run the model n times, I get a relatively constant accuracy across all folds, for each run, with an average accuracy of about 0.85 (note that I have not yet tune the hyperparameters).

However, my values for Recall and Precision show some (significant) deviations. Please note that my random state = None and shuffle = 10. If I change my random state to 100, the results are constant (as it performs the same split/uses the same set). But what I would like to know... are these discrepancies not too high? and is it perhaps due to my data set (which is quite limited, with a total of 2500 data points).

**Recall**
run 1 : class 0 is 0.84 / class 1 is 0.87
run 2 : class 0 is 0.77 / class 1 is 0.99
run 3 : class 0 is 0.76 / class 1 is 1
.......

**Precision**
run 1 : class 0 is 0.85 / class 1 is 0.87
run 2 : class 0 is 0.98 / class 1 is 0.81
run 3: class 0 is 1 / class 1 is 0.83
.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, as you are using `Accuracy`, it means that your dataset is balanced. If this is the case, and you want to get constant or similar precision and recall score, then it will be great if you train your model for `precision_recall_score` or `F1-score`.

As models tend to find patterns in the dataset, the model is giving different precision and recall score every time you run it because it is focusing on the patterns that it is seeing after shuffling the data. That's the nice thing about shuffling the data.

Now, why the `precision` and `recall` score is varying, it's because it's a trade-off between two metric. Our job is to find a `threshold` where there is `maximum precision` and `maximum recall` score. (You can do this by getting probabilities and then run a for loop which will have different threshold values, and it will print precision and recall score every run. You need to pick the maximum value for precision and recall score out of that.)

So, if you want a better accuracy score, then it's a good chance that you are looking into `precision` to be maximum. So you can save the model which gives you best `precision` and `accuracy`. You might do the same with the `recall` as well.

Comment: Thank you Harshad, if I look at my F1 score then it is quite constant for each run, so although my recall and precision differ, the tradeoff is relatively constant. "Our job is to find a threshold where there is maximum precision and maximum recall score. (You can do this by getting probabilities and then run a for loop which will have different threshold values, and it will print precision and recall score every run" Can you explain this a bit more sir, thank you?

Comment: Sure! Make a for loop which will have your threshold values (eg 0 to 1 steps = 0.1). After that make prediction for each and every threshold value and save them in a dictionary which will include threshold value as your key and precision_score as your value. After getting all the results, you can print the maximum precision score and it's threshold key

Comment: Thanks Harshad!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have not done hyperparameter tuning as of yet, but I would be curious to know how deep you are letting your trees grow, as this would obviously materially affect your results. You also mentioned you have a smaller dataset here, so this type of results is to be expected, given the sensitivity (high variance) of DTs.

I would strongly suggest you take a look at using [Random Forest classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)  as opposed to regular decision trees, which doesn't requite too much additional complexity in code, but should address the issues related to the high variance of decision trees you are seeing here.

Additionally, though most still do so, you can actually get away without doing cross-validation for Random Forests, as you can just look at the [OOB score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html)

Hopefully that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it!